# ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.bytecode.instrumentation.internal.FieldInterceptionHelper

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, dependencies

On startup of maven project on tomcat server i get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/bytecode/instrumentation/internal/FieldInterceptionHelper
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.PersistenceUtilHelper.isLoadedWithoutReference(PersistenceUtilHelper.java:121) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider$1.isLoadedWithoutReference(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:171) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:111) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:46) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:128) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:36) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1612) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1597) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:609) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:580) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:524) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:492) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:457) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:407) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:205) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar:5.2.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:852) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.validate(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:367) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:287) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:256) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:346) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:302) ~[spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1575) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.bytecode.instrumentation.internal.FieldInterceptionHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

My dependencies in my pom looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.24-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
        <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Think is may be something to do with hibernate and spring version conflicting. But not too sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems it is because of some transitive dependency conflicts

add

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

exclude hibernate dependent

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
   <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.1.GA</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using spring boot so some of the dependencies were automatically added for me on creation of the project, so getting rid of some of the dependencies in my pom fixed it.